# Foundation 5 Offcanvas issues in IE 9

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with IE 9 and Foundation 5 offcanvas.  The offcanvas sidebar just shows no matter what and overlays the main content.  So basically there is no way to slide the sidebar in and out.  Anyone else having this issue?  it only seems to happen in IE 9.  IE 10-11 is fine, FF and Chrome too.

Issue can be replicated by visiting the docs page using IE8 or simulator
[Zurb-foundation Off Canvas](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add a IE9 conditional at the top of your .html

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

Incase you'r wondering this is the conditionals I'm using (slightly modified boilerplate, for better IE support)

```
<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```